# calling some logic before user is logged out using spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using spring-security 3.x. i have a requirement where in, just before the user is logged out, I want to perform some logic. I wrote a filter extending spring provided `LogoutFilter` as below.

```
public class MyFilter extends LogoutFilter{

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        //Perform some logic 

          super.doFilter(req,res,chain);

   }

}
```

How can I call my own filter when user clicks on logoff button?

Comment: Creating your own filter doesn't make sense. When you log out, it should be notified to the Spring security filter chain. If you need a custom log out filter, then why don't you just implement using `<http>
    <custom-filter before="yourFilter" ref="referneceToFilter" />
</http>`? Additionally, if you were to execute some code logic before you logged out, then there is an appropriate handler provided by Spring. You can just use it.

Comment: I'm confused by the question -- why not just have your logout link/button/whatever first do as you require and then redirect to or call the actual logout process? As Lion has noted, there's no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a custom `LogoutFilter`, you need to plugin one of the following into the standard filter:

- any number of custom `LogoutHandler`s ([javadoc here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html))
- a custom `LogoutSuccessHandler` ([javadoc here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html))

Note that the `LogoutHandler`s are called before the `LogoutSuccessHandler`, but the latter is allowed to throw an exception whereas the former is not supposed to.

Also note that if you use custom `LogoutHandler`s, these need to be given to/injected in the `LogoutFilter` **and** the `ConcurrentSessionFilter` (if used).

If you're using the security namespace in XML config (i.e. `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"`), then it's easy to add a custom `LogoutSuccessHandler` via

```
<http>
    ...
    <logout success-handler-ref="yourBeanId"/>
</http>
```

Not sure how to plugin custom `LogoutHandler`s using the namespace.

Otherwise, it would look something like this:

```
<bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="logoutHandlers"/>
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="your.custom.LogoutSuccessHandler"/>

<bean id="logoutHandlers" class="java.util.Arrays" factory-method="asList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <array>
            <bean class="your.custom.LogoutHandler"/>
            ...
        </array>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```